# How to send structure as array over MPI?

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I have this structure

typedef struct { float x, y, z, vx, vy, vz; } Body;

```
float *buf, *bufSlave;
Body *p;
bytes = nBodies*sizeof(Body);
buf = (float*)malloc(bytes);
p = (Body*)buf;
```

How to send 15 elements with MPI_SEND and how receive with MPI_RECEIVE?

```
MPI_Send(&p[(i - 1) * lung], 6, MPI_FLOAT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I have segmentation fault.

Comment: have you considered machine dependent byte order issues, struct padding issues, and other message scrambling issues in your approach to sending an array of struct?  (assuming your message trafficking will include targeting a broad spectrum of differing computer types)

Comment: yes, but i don't understand how to send...

Comment: It is difficult to help without a reproducible example.

Comment: i have to resolve n-body problem for precision in parallel

Comment: Please edit your question with a [MCVE]. Meanwhile, you can learn about derived datatypes.

Answer (score -1):

First, note that the approach is valid for homogeneous clusters with identical architectures.

For the general case and high stability, choose a safe transport protocol such as JSON or protocol buffers.

Third, boost::serialization into stringstreams can be handy. Similar limitations, but no libraries needed.

Anyways, now the answer: when sending structs as you want to, do so with data type MPI_CHAR and count N * sizeof(Struct)

For receiving, either you already know N or use MPI_Probe and extract count from message. This will be a number of bytes. Allocate a buffer of this size, MPI_RECV into it and reinterpret it as a Buffer array through casting.

The rationale is to go via MPI_CHAR as the struct might have padding.

Comment: is this a sarcastic/humorous answer ? MPI derived datatypes is the best fit (for performance, portability and ease of use) here. And it also works on heterogeneous systems as long as your MPI library can support such configurations.

Comment: The comment is absurd. While it is possibly better to use MPI_FLOAT, the question is about sending  a struct. Copying and packing the array is the only way to use MPI_FLOAT. As we don't know the reason, why the data is in a struct, we should still support the one asking the question.

Comment: `MPI_FLOAT` is **not** a derived datatype. Let’s agree to disagree on everything else.

Comment: I never said anything about MPI_FLOAT. The question is about struct. My answer is correct and you provide only advices that are correct though not fitting the situation of the question.

Comment: I read `MPI_FLOAT` twice in your reply to my comment. You may have never said anything about it, but you definitely wrote twice about. I only mentioned that to state this is not a derived datatype, and I never wrote this should be used. Anyway, let's one more try (try to) agree to disagree.